# Is there a var type equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, types, anonymous-types

So I know that C++ is strongly typed and was just wondering if there was any library (or any thing for that fact of the matter) that would allow you to make a variable that has no initial specific type like var in Python.

Comment: I think this sort of feature has to be supported by the language itself rather than a library.

Comment: C++0x introduces an auto-type, which is similar but defintiely not like Python, which uses late-binding. For C++, the closest you'll get is templates.

Comment: [`auto`](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#auto) is definitely not similar, it only deduces the type for you - still all statically typed.

Comment: It is similar in the way that you don't have to manually type in the type, but that's where the similarity ends.

Comment: Georg: True, but it might be close enough for what the OP needs. It's definitely worth mentioning, at least.

Comment: Right, my reading of *"no initial specific type"* might have been a bit narrow. @jal

Comment: @Xavier Ho: templates are resolved at compile time, so no, templates per-se are not the solution. Depending on the context you can build solutions on top of templates (or with template helpers) though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html) and [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 1):

Two main things come to mind:

1. [`BOOST_AUTO`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.auto)
2. [C++0x type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference)

Comment: Type inference is strongly typed and thus not all the same as a var type.

Comment: Yep `auto` is more like `var` in C#, i think.

Answer (score 0):

In the new C++11, there is the `auto` keyword which no longer refers to automatic duration but rather type inference occurs. So you can do this:

```
auto index = 1; // index is inferred to be int
auto c = 'a' // c is inferred to be a char
```